# How to update google spreadsheet(Drive) automatically from Excel file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a google spreadsheet which should be updated from a windows file everyday. Is there a way API/Script to update the google spreadsheet automatically.

Comment: There is a way... but that's not what you really want to know. Your question needs to be improved. What have you tried? (code if you have it) What is your specific problem? The more detail you can provide, the better help you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the Google Drive file data with the Excel data using [files.update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update). Make sure convert=True is set so that you get a Google Spreadsheet file, not a native Excel document stored in Drive.